# htaccess wildcard subdomain rewrite without infinate loop

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want anything.domain.co.uk to go to a php script which then uses the 'anything' from the url within the html to create different headers for example.
This is the script in my .php file for this

```
<?php echo array_shift(explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));?>
```

I have used the script below but it creates a loop obviously.
How do I get anything.domain.co.uk to pick up the php script, still have anything.domain.co.uk in the url and also have www.domain.co.uk go to 'normal' index page

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.domain.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).domain.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%2.domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Location directive to locate the script you want to target and the use an Allow from to limit access to certain domains:

```
<Location /script.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from anything.domain.co.uk
</Location>
```

Comment: Thanks - not sure how to use that. I'm trying to create dynamic webpages based on the subdomain which is working (eg anything.domain.co.uk) but when I want to exclude the www.domain.co.uk from that script

Comment: Just paste it into your file and change the script.php to your script and anthing.domain to your sub-domain.

Comment: sorry - do you mean paste it into .htaccess? but the subdomains are dynamically created - i.e. a wildcard so do I put a * in

Comment: you will want to use the following syntax for wildcard domains, Allow from .mysite.co.uk